# смещение камеры, когда объект находится передней частью к нам

Tags: c#, unity3d

В данный момент, объект считается стоящим к нам задом - это с позициями `Rotation.y = 0`.
А когда он поворачивается, изменяется `y`, смотря в какую сторону поворачиваем: либо в минус; либо в плюс;

Задача заключается следующая:

Есть скрипт, камера:

```
public class Cam: MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform Target;
    public float Folow = 15f;

    void FixedUpdate() {
        transform.position = new Vector3(Target.position.x+10, Target.position.y+5, Target.position.z-4);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, Target.position, Folow * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

В данный момент, она работает как нужно мне (так все и должно остаться, как написано в коде, то есть, ее наклон должен быть как написано в первой `transform.position`), но как мне сделать так, чтобы камера меняла позицию когда поворачиваемся к нам передом камера расширялась вперед как стоит объект, а в заде уменьшалась?

Мне нужно, чтобы камера разворачивалась, мне нужно чтобы она передвигалась в том же положении, только когда объект поворачивается она передвигается вперед, расширяя обзор спереди, а сзади уменьшается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, сделать дочерний, пустой объект и привязать к нему позицию камеры:

```
public class Cam : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform Target;
    public Rigidbody Rb;

    void FixedUpdate() {
        base.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(base.transform.position, this.Target.position, this.Rb.velocity.magnitude * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

`Target` - это дочерний пустой объект
`Rb` - это родитель основной объект

Answer (score 0):

```
float TurnFactor = Mathf.Abs(Mathf.DeltaAngle(target.transform.eulerAngles.y, gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y))/180f;
Follow = MinFollowRange+AddFollowRange*TurnFactor;
```

TurnFactor будет показывать значение в диапазоне 0f-1f в зависимости от разницы поворотов цели и камеры.
Вот только `Vector3.Lerp(a, p, t)` ты не верно используешь, значение t принимает только 0f-1f, где 0f-a, 1f-b, а 0.5f позиция ровно между a и b. То что у тебя Fol**l**ow = 15, это бессмысленно.

```
gameObject.transform.position = target.transform.position+(target.transform.position-gameObject.transform.position).normalized*Follow;
```

---

Обновление

```
void Update () {
    float MinFollowRange = 2;
    float AddFollowRange = 3;
    float TurnFactor = Mathf.Abs(Mathf.DeltaAngle(Target.eulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.y))/180f;
    float Follow = MinFollowRange+AddFollowRange*TurnFactor;
    transform.position = new Vector3(Target.position.x+10f, Target.position.y+5f, Target.position.z-4f);
    gameObject.transform.position = Target.position+(gameObject.transform.position-Target.position).normalized*Follow;
}
```

В данный момент, она работает как нужно (так все и должно остаться, как написано в коде) =D

Comment: Не работает, этот вариант, камера трясется и вообще ничего не происходит. Вы можете полностью мой скрипт поправить? Я просто не могу никак врубиться. что нужно сделать.

Comment: Всё работает, я просто gameObject.position-Target.position местами перепутал. А тряска наверняка из-за FixedUpdate. Смотри обновление поста.

Comment: А нет, тряска из-за того что после твоих +10 +5 -4 числа становятся целыми. +10f +5f -4f! FixedUpdate всёравно не уместен, используй обычный.

Comment: Работает все равно не так как нужно, он не смещает камеру назад, когда объект смотрит передом к нам, чучуть сдвигает, уже пробовал значения менять, все равно не получается, что-то тут не так.

Comment: У вашей камеры настройка Projection:Orthographic?

Comment: `Perspective`. Нужно, чтобы камера расширялась впереди объекта, она работает, но как-бы не до конца, не всегда срабатывает, когда объект допустим боком стоит, она не расширяется вперед его области видимости. Нужно чтобы 1.Права>>>>> 2.<<<<<Лева 3.Вперед........ 5. ........Назад, я думаю вы поняли. Если нет, изображу на картинке.

Comment: Вроде бы понял. Для усиления эффекта зума у Perspective камеры есть свойство FieldOfView, это угол обзора. Используя значение TurnFactor вы можете прибавлять угол. `Camera.main.fieldOfView = YourBaseFOV+AddFOV*(1-TurnFactor);`

Comment: Пожалуйста исправьте скрипт, чтобы можно было его воспроизвести в готовом виде, а то я не врубаюсь. Хоть убейте не пойму, что куда. буду весьма признателен

Comment: `Update` фризить будет, лучше использовать `FixedUpdate`. Хотя зачем вообще такие сложности делать, не понимаю, тут все банально и просто было.